# How to save contacts on iPhone with broken screen?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I dropped my iPhone and broke the screen (is just black on the left side). So, I bought a new iPhone but I want to sync all my contacts and of course, the screen is locked and moved to the side. It looks something like the image below.

[image: iPhone broken screen image - half black]

On the lock screen I can only see numbers given below.

```
12
45
78
0
```

Now, I can't unlock my phone to sync to iCloud. How can I save my contacts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already syncing your contacts via iCloud, then you can sync them to your computer in iTunes in the Info screen. Then you can sync the computer's contacts to iCloud and so get them onto your new phone that way.

Alternatively, you could try backing up your current phone (Summary screen) and then restoring the backup to your new phone.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To save your data, you’ll need to backup and/or sync with iTunes (Windows) or Apple Finder (macOS).

The one issue you have to overcome is being able to *unlock* the device to allow it to synchronize.  You will need the following:

- Lightning to USB3 Adapter
- Any USB keyboard

Simply, plug the adapter into the phone and the keyboard into the adapter.  After a couple of seconds, you’ll be able to hit <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the unlock screen. Then, just enter your pin which will unlock the phone.  Once unlocked, you can synch all of your contacts, music, pictures, etc.

I tested a wired 10-key keypad and a Logitech K380 wireless keyboard with Unifying Receiver.